# Using vbscript to log into chrome web page

Tags: google-chrome, vbscript

I found this script to login to a webpage via IE

```
Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
oIE.Visible = True
oIE.navigate WebPath

Do
WScript.Sleep 250
Loop While oIE.ReadyState < 4 And oIE.Busy

oIE.Document.All.Item("username").Value = sUser
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("password").Value = sPass
WScript.Sleep 250
oIE.Document.All.Item("login").Click
```

I would like to login to a website using chrome and so far I have

```
Dim iURL 
Dim objShell

iURL = "https://cag.saasloans.com/lp/provident/Logon.do"

set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "chrome.exe", iURL, "", "", 1
```

I could use

User name

```
WshShell.SendKeys "******"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
```

Password

```
WshShell.SendKeys "******"
```

Is there a better way I can do this?

Comment: I found something that works                                                               set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("https://cag.saasloans.com/lp/provident/Logon.do", 1, false) 'This will open your default browser

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Quit()